# swift | Nothing in multiple TableView with custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift5

This is my code. I checked IBOulets connection, Identifier, class names.
and find some question and answer which on same boat. but didn't words.
what did I missed? Thank you for reading. :)

**HomeViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

struct Label {
    let top: String
    let day: String
    let summary: String
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var upperTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lowerTableView: UITableView!
    
    let upperCellID = "UpperTableViewCell"
    let lowerCellID = "LowerTableViewCell"
    
    var dateString: String!
    
    var labels: [Label] = [
        Label(top: "title1", day: "2023.10.1.", summary: "Test"),
        Label(top: "title2", day: "2023.10.2.", summary: "Test"),
        Label(top: "title3", day: "2023.10.3.", summary: "Test")
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        // Upper Table (Your To-Do)
        upperTableView.delegate = self
        upperTableView.dataSource = self
        upperTableView.register(UpperTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: upperCellID)
        
        // Lower Table (Your To-Do)
        lowerTableView.delegate = self
        lowerTableView.dataSource = self
        lowerTableView.register(LowerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: lowerCellID)
    }
    
    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation
     
     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */
    
}


extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    // These are working!
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch tableView {
        case upperTableView:
            print("you tabbed me!(Upper)")
        case lowerTableView:
            print("Below!")
        default:
            print("outside of table.")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var returnCell: UITableViewCell?
        
        if tableView == self.upperTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.upperCellID, for: indexPath) as! UpperTableViewCell
            cell.topLabel?.text = labels[indexPath.row].top
            returnCell = cell
        } else if tableView == lowerTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.lowerCellID, for: indexPath) as! LowerTableViewCell
            cell.titleLabel?.text = labels[indexPath.row].top
            returnCell = cell
        }
        return returnCell!
    }
}
```

**UpperTableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class UpperTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var summaryLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**LowerTableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class LowerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image: Identifier Example]

[image: The Screen]

I tried show labels in my upper and lower TableView.
but there is nothing showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `upperTableView.register` and `lowerTableView.register` calls. You *already* registered the cells by adding them to the storyboard and giving them identifiers.

If you call `register` in code, the identifiers will instead be registered to the cell class, not to the views you designed in the storyboard. When you dequeue a cell, it would *not* create an instance of the cell in the storyboard (it would call one of the other `init`s your cell class has), and so the outlets you declared are all `nil`.

Comment: Oh my god! It's works!!! Great Thanks!!